# Improving database structure in one to many relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a database to keep track on various statistics on my self and I'm wondering if there's a better way to store multiple entries for a single date.

E.g. from my table I have AllergyMedicine which can track multiple medicines taken on the same date, is there a better way to do this?

Also the tables Food and Allergy seems unnecessary, is there a better way to group tables?

Any suggestions are appreciated!
[image: DB Schema]

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: You might get better results if you specify the phenomena you're trying to model. It's very unusual to have a "date" table as a foreign key.

Comment: Should I change "Date" table into id, date and refer to id instead of date? I'm trying to create a create a database with daily sats, where I might take multiple meds in one day and have multiple meals.

Comment: Can't judge a schema without knowing what the queries will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it helps to state the problem in a semi structured way, as below.

```
The system monitors one or more **persons**.
Each person consumes zero or more **items**. Each consumption has an attribute of date and time. 
Items can be **food**, or **medicines**.
Food can be of the types **snack**, **fruit** or **meal**.
A meal has a **type**.
A person may report **symptoms**. Each report will cover a period of time, and be reported at a specific date/time.
Symptoms may be associated with zero or more **allergies**.
```

I do not believe that "date" is an entity in your schema - it's an attribute of events that occur, e.g. consuming something, or noticing a symptom.

If the statements above are true, the schema might be:

### Persons

- ID
- name
- ...

### FoodItemType

- ID
- Name

### FoodItem

- ID
- Name
- FoodItemTypeID (FK)

### Medicine

- ID
- Name

### FoodConsumption

- PersonID
- FoodID
- ConsumptionDateTime

### MedicineConsumption

- PersonID
- MedicineID
- ConsumptionDateTime

### Symptom

- ID
- Name
- ....

### SymptomObservation

- PersonID
- SymptomID
- SymptomStartDateTime
- SymptomEndDateTime
- SymptomReportDateTime

### Allergy

- ID
- Name

### AllergySymptom

- AllergyID
- SymptomID

Comment: Thanks, your way of structuring makes it more apparent how to model the db. I'll try to apply it and redo mine.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you take more than one medicine on one day, why not isolate that day (=date) in its own table?

So you'll have a table "days" with only dates, that you either prefill (like a calendar) or only fill with those days when you really took that medicine.

That way, you save a lot of space by "centering" the date in one table and relating everything else to it. Which is actually a very precise model of reality.

All your "FoodSnack", "FoodMeal", "AllergyMedicine" etc. with a date in them will become plain N:M mapping tables then.

You could even abstract further, reduce tables and make just three tables:

- symptoms
- causes
- treatment

All of those related to the central "day" table (I wouldn't call it "Date", cause that's a keyword and easily mistaken also), plus related to each other, where applicable.

Comment: Isn't that what I have done with the "Date" table? Are you suggesting that I delete tables "Food" and "Allergy" and relate Allergy Medicine directly to "Date" table?

Comment: Yes - your are 1) having certain allergic symptoms on a day, 2) taking certain medication/food/whatever on a day, which are actually also related to a specific allergy (and so on).

You could even abstract further, reduce tables and make just three tables: symptoms, causes, treatment! all of those related to the central "day" table (I wouldn't call it "Date", cause that's a keyword and easily mistaken also), plus related to each other, where applicable. Atm, you have a schema which I'd consider way too complex and redundant.